# In Ubuntu, How to set Tomcat 9 to use Java 17?

Tags: linux, spring-boot, tomcat9, java-17

As the title described, in Ubuntu 20.04 how to set Tomcat 9 to use Java 17 ?

Recently I repacked the **war** file of my web project with Spring Boot 3.0.1 which requires Java 17 to run, trying to deploy it to Tomcat 9 container at an Ubuntu 20.04 server.

It seems that the best way is to utilize the `setenv.sh`.

I've followed some documents,
created a folder `bin` in `/usr/share/tomcat9`, touched file of `setenv.sh`,
edited its content with `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`.

Then run `sudo systemctl start tomcat9`, but failed.
`sudo systemctl status tomcat9` said "No JDK or JRE found - Please set the JAVA_HOME variable or install the default-jdk package",

Installed **openjdk-17-jre-headless**, and removed **openjdk-11-jre-headless** at first. Both Tomcat9 and JRE 17 is installed by **apt** package manager.

Comment: looks like you did not export JAVA_HOME to your environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you managed to run tomcat 9 with `java 17`, a web app using **spring boot 3.x** or **spring framework 6.x** would still not be able to run there.

Reason is that starting with spring boot 3.0 or spring framework 6.0 the web application needs to conform to jakarta servlet api. According to [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for tomcat the jakarta servlet api (servlet v5.0) is supported from **tomcat 10** and later.

As described in doc

> Apache Tomcat 10.0.x
>
> Apache Tomcat 10.0.x builds on Tomcat 9.0.x and
> implements the **Servlet 5.0**, JSP 3.0, EL 4.0, WebSocket 2.0 and
> Authentication 2.0 specifications (**the versions required by Jakarta EE
> 9 platform**).

So you have to use tomcat 10 instead of tomcat 9.

Answer (score 6):

Well I have found this thread after finding the answer so I will write my solution If it can help anyone :

Operating system : Ubuntu 22.04

Installing Java : apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk

Adding JAVA_HOME : nano /etc/environment

-> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"

Then

Installing Tomcat9 with : apt-get install tomcat9

Starting tomcat9 with : service tomcat9 start

An error is following stating **JAVA_HOME** is not found which is incorrect.

You need to find the script **/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-locate-java.sh**

Which actually seach for the versions 11 to 8 of Java.

Updating the script this way adding the version 17 is solving the issue  :

```
    find_jdks()
{
    for java_version in 17 11 10 9 8
    do
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I also had to uninstall the default-j* packages (default-jdk default-jdk-headless default-jre default-jre-headless)

Comment: Okay. Though it is impossible to make Spring Boot 3 run with Tomcat9 ...